# Preferred way to check object property is `null` or `undefined`

Tags: javascript, object, logic

If I have some object that has a **property** that *may or may not* exist, is there a preferred way to check for its' existence?

```
// Good?
(someObj.property !== undefined && someObj.property !== null)

// Better?
(typeof someObj.property !== 'undefined')

// Best?
(someObj.property != null)
```

*The last `!=` operator is [on purpose:](http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/#equality)

> Strict equality checks (`===`) must be used in favor of abstract equality checks (`==`). The only exception is when checking for `undefined` and `null` by way of `null`. The use of `== null` is also acceptable in cases where only one of `null` or `undefined` may be logically encountered, such as uninitialized variables.

Comment: The first and the last are equivalent. The middle one won't check `null` values. So first it depends on what you want. Then it depends on how much you want to type ;) Whether or not to use `!= null` is a personal preference.

Comment: if(someObj.property) for everything except booleans ?

Comment: @Jonasw: And empty strings, `0`, `NaN`.

Comment: What is an existing property? Are falsey values existing?

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you'd use **obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: Depends on whether `null` values should be considered or not.

Comment: Please provide more details for your link. Check out [answer] for more details.

Comment: Wouldn't that be checking for the value of the property and not whether the property itself exists?